# Angular - cannot send data to Child Component after resetting it's value

Tags: angular

In my app I have two components - let's call them Parent and Child. On click I'm sending data from Parent to Child and displaying it. But in Child component I also have the ability to clear incoming data - set incoming data to null. After cleaning I can no longer send and display data from Parent to Child. Here's the snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1zdvqj?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in the `ChildComponent` when you set the `id` to `null`. You are updating only the local reference. The `ParentComponent` has no idea that the `ChildComponent` has internally set the value of `id` to `null`. Therefore, the `ChildComponent` needs to emit the change and inform `ParentComponent` of the changes done.

To fix this we have `[()]` banana in the box operator and the `@Output` `EventEmitter` concepts.

In your `ParentComponent.html`, change your `ChildComponent` input to 2-way binding:

```
<app-child [(id)]="elementId"></app-child>
```

In your `ChildComponent`, add a new `EventEmitter` to inform any change that is done for the input `id`.

```
@Output() idChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Then in your `reset` function, emit the updated value;

```
reset() {
    this.id = null;
    this.idChange.emit(this.id);
}
```

When the updated `id` is emitted from `ChildComponent`; it is received in the `ParentComponent` and the `ParentComponent` then updates its reference to `null` as well.

Read more:

1. Angular 2-way binding: https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding
2. Inputs and Outputs: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is 2-Way-Binding. You can read about it here:
https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

It says

> Basics of two-way binding
> Two-way binding does two things:
>
> Sets a specific element property.
> Listens for an element change event.

What you miss is the the very last point.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-98vvnu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

In this forked stackblitz I added the () within the parent template, and the output within the child component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  id: number;

  @Output()
  idChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  reset() {
    this.id = null;
    this.idChange.emit(this.id);
  }
}
```

```
<app-child
  [(id)]="elementId"
></app-child>
```